# DHCP multiple WAN

Tags: networking, windows-server-2012-r2, group-policy, subnet, dhcp-server

There is a network, DHCP enabled: **192.168.28.0/22** (WINDOWS SERVER 2012R2)

There is 2 WAN connections:

**WAN1 (192.168.28.1)**

**WAN2 (192.168.29.1)**

I want to tell DHCP that domain users go to WAN1, ALL OTHER USERS go to WAN2

Since the subnet is **255.255.252.0**, i want to configure dhcp like this:

192.168.**28**.1 -> 192.168.**28**.254 USE WAN1 (DOMAIN USERS)

192.168.**29**.1 -> 192.168.**29**.254 USE WAN2 (OTHER USERS)

Basically i need to separate users in a same network. I dont know if it can be done by DHCP or GPO or etc..? But it should be simple. Whoever has an account use WAN1. thats it.

Thanks.

Comment: You say user, but are you wanting to do this per-user or per-machine?

Comment: @SmallLoanOf1M user

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could send everyone to the "unauthenticated" default gateway, then use a logon script to change the authenticated users to the correct default gateway with a command like:

route add -p 0.0.0.0 mask 0.0.0.0 192.168.28.1

Comment: Thats a perfect idea! in this case, there is a default gateway that all users get. Then, whoever login, their gateway changes to the new one!
Works on all phones, tablets, laptops, all devices?

Answer (score 0):

DHCP is giving the client device an address and gateway before authentication, so has no idea if it's a domain user or not.

Correct way is to VLAN off the unauthenticated users.  This requires a switch that is able to pass DHCP requests to a DHCP server (DHCP Helper or Relay).  The relay appends information to the DHCP request so Server 2012 would know which network it came on and serve up DHCP addresses appropriately.  Each DHCP scope will have it's own gateway address.

Comment: How about Active Directory? is there anyway to change the account setting on domain users to use another gateway?

Comment: The closest you could probably get to controlling the egress via AD would be to set a proxy in the browser via group policy.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Bitterrooter.  This is your only chance to get this done correct and avoid revisit or worse, chasing network ghosts.

Setup varies and you have dozens of options.  You can do achieve using a manage switch with some simple configs - I suggest lab first.  VLAN misconfigs can bring network to it's knees.

One product I run into a lot are SonicWALL's.  I will post a diagram based on using a SonicWALL to do this.  Not what I recommend you do, this is just an example.  I am betting you have access to a SonicWALL too, they are everywhere, maybe retired, but it works for this test.

I hope this helps put you on the right path.  Remember, you can setup similar config using L3 switch - more common.  This example is easy, because I find that most a lot of people like pictures.  I can provide configs for any Dell, AdTran or Cisco setup.  If you request, I will assume you know how to TFTP, USB, etc to running.

It may seem harder but only because I am giving you details.  This will take 5 minutes to setup, if you have all the parts for your test.

1. SonicWALL NSA 220.
2. PowerConnect N2024.

A. WWW Connection on SonicWALL Interface X1
B. WWW Connection on SonicWALL Interface X2

SonicWALL Interface X0 is where the default LAN is configured as: 192.168.168.168.

XO = 192.168.168.168.
Create Sub-Interface on X0 for:

X0:10 = 192.168.28.0/24 with gateway as: 192.168.28.1
X0:11 = 192.168.29.0/24 with gateway as: 192.168.29.1

The cable from SonicWALL PORT X0 connects to Dell Switch on PORT 1.  Dell Switch PORT 1 needs to be set as General or Trunk mode, tagging VLAN 10 and 11 is important.  Now for the PC's.

Let's say for example you have 5 computers for each subnet.

Configure port 5-9 for the first 5 computers on subnet 192.168.28.0.  Configure those ports (5-9) as ACCESS MODE for VLAN 10.

Configure port 10-14 for the other 5 computers on subnet 192.168.29.0.  Configure those ports (10-14) as ACCESS MODE for VLAN 11.

Then you can go to the DHCP section where you can literally create DHCP Scopes specifically for any VLAN or subnets.  You will be able to create a DHCP server for X0:10 and X0:11.  Now it depends how fancy you go, you may need to utilize IP Helper.  Depends.

Now, the reason why this method works for a lot of people is because it's quick and easy to get to and easy to detect issues.  A lot of folks struggle or just chose to not see the power of commands\SSH.  That said, environment and budgets always decide so that's why I am down to help any situation.  Better that I try versus.  At least it's one experience to compare to.

Check out diagram I drew. Hopefully it makes sense and helps you.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VnwBh.jpg)